# What does \ mean in Spring Security Roles Hierarchy Expression?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-1.0a

```
security:
  jwt:
    issuer: "https://localhost.com"
  rolesHierarchyExpression:
    ROLE_FATHER > ROLE_LORD \
    ROLE_VASSAL > ROLE_HUMBLE_SERVANT
    ROLE_KNIGHT > ROLE_HUMBLE_SERVANT
...
```

I was wondering in the application yml, what does \ mean? This is Spring Security Oauth 1.0.0.

Comment: Where did you see this? Any link?

Comment: @dur That example I have written is based off a code base I was looking into. It seems like the pattern is when the roles on the right are the same (meaning to the right of the > sign) and they appear subsequently, then those lines don't have a backslash, otherwise lines end in a backslash. Maybe it's just code style or maybe it's like a line terminate. Any ideas?